# How do I ensure all loops finish in the same time in Parallel.For?

Tags: c#, loops, parallel-processing

In C# (.NET), I got 2 loops ->

```
A for ... do:
{
    B for do:
      { something}

something that evaluates all "for"s in B loop
}
```

I used Parallel.For for the inner loop but the results of those loops varied every time I ran the application. I think it may be a result of Some asynchrounous work, but I am not sure how to be sure about it in VS 2005 Express, moreover I am not sure If I am supposed to do something Like "Wait until Parallel.For is finished, then do the stuff for all of it.

EDIT (due to comment which requests some more specific information):

```
 for (int i = 0; i < max; i++) //Pre Vsetky retazce ..
       {
           prefix = 0;
           tempsame.Clear();
           bool spracovane = true;
           int dlzkaI = Items[i, 1].Length;

           if (Items[i, 2] != "1") { spracovane = false; } 

           if (spracovane == false)
         //  Parallel.For(0, max, delegate(int j)
         //    {
                  for (int j = 0; j < max; j++) //Pre kazdy dalsi
                  {

                       int dlzkaJ = Items[j, 1].Length;

                       if (dlzkaJ >= dlzkaI)
                       {

                           CompareInfo myComp = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.CompareInfo;
                           bool isprefix = myComp.IsPrefix(Items[j, 1], Items[i, 1]);


                           bool issame = false;

                           if (dlzkaJ.Equals(dlzkaI)) issame = true;

                           if (isprefix == true && issame == false)
                           {
                               prefix++;
                           }

                           else if (isprefix == true && issame == true && prefix == 0) 
                           {
                               tempsame.Add(Items[j, 0]);

                           }
                       }
                } 





   if ((prefix==0) && (spracovane==false))
   {
       Items = UpdateUnique(tempsame.ToArray(typeof(string)) as string[], Items);
       unique++;

   }
   }
```

In short, the 2 loops loop through same array of strings and choose only unique strings -> it means that the string can't be a prefix to any other string.

```
> Car - unique Car - unique Cafeteria -
> unique Automobile - unique Auto - not
> unique - it's prefix of Automobile
> Auto - not unique
```

Comment: I guess we need to see more specifics like what kinds of things you do in you loops. Also your "something that evaluates all "for"s in B loop}" description looks ambiguous.

Answer (score 1):

If your two looks have interactions with external variables or side effects, then your result may end up non-deterministic. That's one explanation, and you should check these looks for interaction. Seeing how your loops are *inset*, consider doing `Parallel.For` on just the outer loop.

One other explanation might be that PFX is not a stable tech yet - it yields lots of bizarre errors, so I would wait for .NET 4/VS 2010 and use it them.

Oh, and if you are doing some math algorithm and want the absolute top performance, I wouldn't use .NET at all - OpenMP is way better, not to mention Threading Building Blocks and the like.

Good luck!

Comment: Yes, but I am not going to study another way of coding because of one application / code. Can you check my problem again please? I added specific code.

Answer (score 1):

Without studying the code in detail, there is one obvious potential problem, in that your inner `Parallel.For` loop increments and inspects the `prefix` variable which is declared outside the parallel loop.

This means that the parallel iterations may function differently depending on which thread first increments this variable.